# How can we skip bad lines(expected more fields saw less) from a dataset using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataset, data-science

I know we can solve this error using `on_bad_lines = 'skip'`. This solves the error when we are having more no. of values than columns then those lines are skipped while reading into dataframe but it doesn't skip the rows having less no. of values than the columns

e.g. Consider a dataset like below

```
c1, c2, c3
1, 2, 3
4, 34, 56
34, 45, 23, 32
2, 3
21, 32, 324,34
1
12, 23, 233
```

when I used `df = pd.read_csv(dataset, sep= ',', encoding= 'unicode_escape', on_bad_lines = 'skip')`

It skipped the lines having more than 3 values but threw an error at the line which has less no. of values.

How can we skip the lines those are having less number of values than the columns?

So that the df should look like this

```
c1, c2, c3
1, 2, 3
4, 34, 56
12, 23, 233
```

Comment: In the output the rows having less than 3 values are not present

Comment: @Will That is how I am expecting the output should look like but it is throwing errors when the values it the rows are less than 3. The exact error that we get is this pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 26940

Comment: how's your data looking like, when you do not use the encoding= 'unicode_escape' and print it?

Comment: Have you tried with `error_bad_lines=False` ?

Comment: @ABHISHEKD Its pretty normal I guess. Earlier I ran into a different error for a different file so that's why I am keeping the encoding = 'unicode_escape' for generalizing the reading of datasets but I tried removing the encoding and I still got the error which I am talking about so mostly encoding won't be the cause here.

Comment: Yes @Will I tried with error_bad_lines= False as well but still got the error

Comment: according to your data you can do one thing, just read the data normally. for all the empty variables you will see NaN. then you can ignore all the data which has Nan

Comment: error is data specific on line 26940. You may want to check that line in your csv. For rows with less values, those you can be dropped using dropna() once data is loaded

Comment: Hey @ABHISHEKD Thanks for pointing out that if the values are not passed then it will be considered as Nan. I saw the error once more and saw my actual data the above data that I used was for eg. purpose I found out that it was being caused due to the existence of a double quote in one of the fields. Using quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE solved the problem